# sortname for editor messes up crossrefed entry

Tags: biblatex, biber, sorting

In the .bib-file there are two relevant entries -- the crucial point is `sortname`, for (by using `prefix=true`) I want to print **De** Jong, Irene J. F., René Nünlist und Angus M. Bowie but sort the collection without the "von"-part of de Jong's name:

**J** ohnstone, Mark A. `book`

De **J** ong, Irene J. F., Renee Nünlist und Angus M. Bowie `collection`

**K** amtekar, Rachana `article`

```
  @Collection{JongNuenlistBowie:Narrators,
   editor =  {Irene J. F. de Jong AND Ren{\'e} N{\"u}nlist AND
              Angus M. Bowie},
   sortname = {Jong, Irene J. F. de AND Rene{\'e} N{\"u}nlist AND
              Angus M. Bowie},
   gender =  {pp},
   title =   {Narrators, Narratees, and Narratives in Ancient
              Greek Literature},
   booktitle = {Narrators, Narratees, and Narratives in Ancient
                Greek Literature},
   shorttitle = {Narrators},
   language =  {english},
   year =    2004,
   titleaddon = {Studies in Ancient Greek Narrative, Volume~1},
   booktitleaddon = {Studies in Ancient Greek Narrative, Volume~1},
   series =  {Mnemosyne. Supplementum},
   number =  257,
   publisher = {Brill},
   location ={Leiden AND Boston}
}

@InCollection{Morgan:PlatoNarrative,
 author =    {Kathryn A. Morgan},
 gender =    {sf},
 title =     {Plato},
 language =  {english},
 crossref =  {JongNuenlistBowie:Narrators},
 editor =    {Irene J. F. de Jong AND Ren{\'e} N{\"u}nlist AND
              Angus M. Bowie},
 year  =     2004,
 booktitle = {Narrators, Narratees, and Narratives in Ancient
              Greek Literature},
 booktitleaddon = {Studies in Ancient Greek Narrative, Volume~1},
 series =    {Mnemosyne. Supplementum},
 number =    257,
 publisher = {Brill},
 location =  {Leiden AND Boston},
 chapter =   28,
 pages =     {357-76}
}
```

Now, biblatex uses the `sortname` of the `collection` also for the names of the author in a `crossref`- (*not* `xref`-)entry and prints `Morgan, Kathryn A. 2004 »Plato«, Englisch, in de Jong u. a. (2004), Kap. 28, S. 357–76` after the De Jong-Collection and before the article by Kamtekar.

**J** ohnstone, Mark A. `book`

De **J** ong, Irene J. F., René Nünlist und Angus M. Bowie `collection`

**M** organ, Kathryn A. `InCollection`

**K** amtekar, Rachana `article`

How can I use sortname for the editors but not for the authors in a collection?

BTW: I use tlmgr with the latest updates, biber, and biblatex with the following option:

```
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, sortlocale=de, sorting=nyvt,
        babel=hyphen, alldates=terse,
        annotation=true, useprefix=true,
        pagetracker=true, volnumformat=default, datezeros=false, 
        pagetracker=spread, bibencoding=auto, 
        publocformat= loccolonpub, backend=biber,
        citetracker = constrict, ibidtracker=constrict, 
        opcittracker=constrict, idemtracker=constrict, 
        relatedformat=parens]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try this - define a custom inheritance rule to avoid inheriting `sortname`. Add this to your preamble:

```
\DeclareDataInheritance{collection}{incollection}{%
  \noinherit{sortname}
}
```

This way, the `INCOLLECTION` doesn't inherit the `sortname`.